# Android: Detect layout parameter "fill_parent" and "wrap_content"

Tags: android

I'm working on a android app where I draw a red circle on the screen. Now I want to capture the layout parameters "wrap_content" and "fill_parent" because I want to change the size of the circle for each parameter layout type by a `onMeasureCallback()` function.

If I try now, the height and width are always the same by using "wrap_content" and "fill_parent".

**activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#FFFFFF"> 

    <com.example.myapplication.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawing_circle_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"  // this must be a different width than by using fill_parent-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" // this must be a different height than by using fill_parent-->
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**DrawingView**

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

    // setup initial color
    private final int paintColor = Color.RED;
    // defines paint and canvas
    private Paint drawPaint;
    private float size;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // set standards
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        // setting up paint
        setupPaint();

        // set on measure call back
        setOnMeasureCallback();
    }

    // Setup paint with color and stroke styles
    private void setupPaint() {
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(size, size, size, drawPaint);
    }

    private void setOnMeasureCallback() {
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                // how can I detect here which layout parameter I've used in the main_activity view?
            }
        });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
        } else {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: override `onMeasure`, no need for `ViewTreeObserver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `getLayoutParams().height`, `getLayoutParams().width`. There should be constant values for `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: that's where I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by reverse engineering the data in onMeasure.  But the View isn't really passed this information directly.  Instead they're passed a MeasureSpec, which will give a size and a constant for EXACT, AT_MOST, or UNSPECIFIED and let the view set its own size.  Look at what values you get for each of them there.